# .htaccess file to allow access from another document of the same site

Tags: .htaccess

I need to allow access to a PHP document only if I try to access from another document of the same website, all the `.htaccess` examples that I have tried didn't work.

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from */esi3d/*
Deny from all
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the content of the most recent `.htaccess` file you have attempted that is not working.

Comment: The question is edited

Comment: How are your php files accessing this php document?

Comment: like this  `<li><a href=<?php echo base_url('index.php/editor')?>>Editor</a></li>`. I'm using codeigniter